# Adding classes to menu items

Tags: 7, routes

Hi I am developing a custom module for menus and I want to add active class to menu items based on the current path. For this I have tried `theme_menu_link()` but this function only provides the mlid(menu link ID) of the original links and not all the menu items. But I need the mlid of all individual menu links.

Is there any alternate hook for this functionality, or any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

have a look at `l()` function in `includes/common.inc`:

```
...
if (($path == $_GET['q'] || ($path == '<front>' && drupal_is_front_page())) &&
    (empty($options['language']) || $options['language']->language == $language_url->language)) {
  $options['attributes']['class'][] = 'active';
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to retrieve the mlid of all the menu items so that I can match the path based on menu link ids

Comment: @SomyaGupta Please consider choose the best answer for your query. This will hep us to close the Question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my jQuery solution, the advantage is you dont need to add a menu/alter hook.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.href;
        $('a').each(function() {
            var cur_a_url = $(this).attr('href');
            if(cur_a_url == pathname) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
});
```

But [THIS](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/29516/4471) is the perfect Drupal way.